# Define and plot a function in python

Tags: python, numpy, function, graph

f(x) = X*2
X - 2
X*1/2

WITH DOMAIN X = (-4,2)

```
def f(x): x**2
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, myfunc(x))
ax.axhline(ls='--', c='k', label='$f(x)$')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('$f(x)$', fontsize=12)
ax.legend(fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the question? Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I basically only added a `return` statement to the definition of the square.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DOMAIN = (-4, 2)
POINTS = 100
def f(x):
    """Square x."""
    return x**2

x = np.linspace(*DOMAIN, POINTS)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, f(x), label='f(x)')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.legend()
```

Or is your function supposed to be `f(x)=x**(2*x) - 2np.sqrt(x)`? In that case, it returns complex numbers beyond `x<0`, due to the square root of negative `x` values. Then, you can perhaps resort to something like [this](https://gist.github.com/cswiercz/1fde0a82f8e9e1b0660a)?